# How to build a digital map for a building?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am required to build a digital indoor map for my school building. I need this to help provide indoor localization for the building. The map has to be in kml format.

I am not able to figure out a way to build the map digitally. All i can think of is draw/connect geo-codes that can shape the indoor plan in google earth.

If any body could share their opinions.. I would be grateful!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out [Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/)? It allows you to model buildings, save as KML and display in Google Earth.

Comment: I will try this. The objective of making these digital indoor maps is to be able to provide navigation across the built map. I was wondering after using Google SketchUp to make my indoor maps, will i be able to support the navigation feature? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a [ground overlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays) within the maps api. Then you can create an image of your floor plan and then overlay it on your map. The corresponding KML element to use is [GroundOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#groundoverlay).